# External Script to Wrap String in Quotes

Tags: awk, sed, intellij-idea

I often test a SQL query, and then need to paste that into a Java IDE as a string.

For example:

```
 SELECT
  col1,
  col2
FROM table
WHERE....
```

should become:

```
+ " SELECT "
+ " col1, "
+ " col2 "
+ " FROM table "
+ " WHERE...."
```

I want to run an external script in my IDE (please see pic of screen to define it) to do this, but am having trouble coming up with the script.  I've tried various forms of awk and bash printf, but I end up with either garbage or just the quotes at the beginning and end, not each line.

Has anyone done anything like this before?

This is my latest try.  It removes the \n's and only wraps the entire string, not each line.  Thanks for any advice.

```
#!/bin/bash 
awk '{printf("+\"%s\"\n", $0);}'  <<< $1
```

[image]

FOLLOWUP

I ended up with the following script on the command line. It works fine. The underlying problem was that I did not have quotes around the $1 parameter, thus it was discarding the line feeds

```
#!/bin/bash 
#
# Print the first line (NR==1) with the String variable initialization.
# Print subsequent lines starting with a "+" and the contents wrapped in quotes.
#

echo "$1" | awk 'NR==1 {printf("  String sqlText = \"%s \"\n", $0)} NR>1 {printf(" + \"       %s \"\n", $0);}'
```

I outputs something like this.  After my IDE aligns everything, it looks fine.  You may need to adjust the leading spaces to suit your settings.

```
String sqlText = "SELECT "
     + "            col1, "
     + "            col2, "
     + "            col3, "
     + "            col4, "
     + "          FROM my table "
```

Answer (score 0):

The below sed command removes all the leading and trailing spaces in each line and adds `+ "` at the starting and `"`(*space,"*) at the end.

```
$ sed 's/^\s*\(.*\)\s*$/+ " \1 "/g' file
+ " SELECT "
+ " col1, "
+ " col2 "
+ " FROM table "
+ " WHERE.... "
```